# Pyspark join dataframe on comma separted values in a column

Tags: apache-spark-sql, pyspark

So i have two data frames which i want to join. The catch is the second table has comma separted values stored in it out of which one matches with the column in Table A. How do I it in Pyspark. Below is an example

Table A has

```
+-------+--------------------+
|deal_id|           deal_name|
+-------+--------------------+
| 613760|ABCDEFGHI           |
| 613740|TEST123             |
| 598946|OMG                 |
```

Table B has

```
+-------+---------------------------+--------------------+
|                            deal_id|           deal_type|                           
+-------+---------------------------+--------------------+
| 613760,613761,613762,613763       |Direct De           |
| 613740,613750,613770,613780,613790|Direct              |
| 598946                            |In                  |
```

Expected Result - Join table A and Table B when there is a match with Table A's deal ID against Table B's comma separted value. For instance TableA.dealid - 613760 is in table B's 1 st row, i want that row returned.

```
+-------+--------------------+---------------+
|deal_id|           deal_name|      deal_type|
+-------+--------------------+---------------+
| 613760|ABCDEFGHI           |Direct De      |     
| 613740|TEST123             |Direct         |
| 598946|OMG                 |In             |
```

Any assistance is appreciated. I need it in pyspark.

Thanks.

Comment: join using find_in_set: `dfA.alias('d1').join(dfB.alias('d2'), expr('find_in_set(deal_id,l_id) > 0'), 'left').select('d1.*', 'd2.deal_type')`   https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.0/api/sql/index.html#find_in_set

Comment: I tried this code ```merg_orders_df = dfA.alias('d1').join(dfB.alias('d2'),F.expr('F.find_in_set (d1.deal_id, d2.deal_id) > 0'),'full_outer').select('d1.deal_id','d2.deal_id')```  I am getting Attribute error saying AttributeError: module 'pyspark.sql.functions' has no attribute 'find_in_set'. Kindly help fix the code

Comment: `find_in_set` is an Spark SQL builtin function which is invoked from F.expr() function, so just remove `F.` from the `F.find_in_set`

Comment: Perfect... Worked like a charm.. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Sample data

```
from pyspark.sql.types import IntegerType, LongType, StringType, StructField, StructType

tuples_a = [('613760', 'ABCDEFGHI'),
            ('613740', 'TEST123'),
            ('598946', 'OMG'),
           ]

schema_a = StructType([
         StructField('deal_id', StringType(), nullable=False),
         StructField('deal_name', StringType(), nullable=False)
        ])


tuples_b = [('613760,613761,613762,613763 ', 'Direct De'),
            ('613740,613750,613770,613780,613790', 'Direct'),
            ('598946', 'In'),
           ]

schema_b = StructType([
         StructField('deal_id', StringType(), nullable=False),
         StructField('deal_type', StringType(), nullable=False)
        ])        

df_a = spark_session.createDataFrame(data=tuples_a, schema=schema_a)
df_b = spark_session.createDataFrame(data=tuples_b, schema=schema_b)
```

You need to split the column and explode it in order to join.

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import split, col, explode

df_b = df_b.withColumn('split', split(col('deal_id'), ','))\
           .withColumn('exploded', explode(col('split')))\
           .drop('deal_id', 'split')\
           .withColumnRenamed('exploded', 'deal_id')


df_a.join(df_b, on = 'deal_id', how = 'left_outer')\
    .show(10, False)
```

and the expected result

```
+-------+---------+---------+
|deal_id|deal_name|deal_type|
+-------+---------+---------+
|613760 |ABCDEFGHI|Direct De|
|613740 |TEST123  |Direct   |
|598946 |OMG      |In       |
+-------+---------+---------+
```